# Why Apache IoTDB Version 0.12.4 got stuck and did not report any error after all night running data?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use version 0.12.4 of Apache IoTDB, and I ran data writing all night. Today I want to use SQL to query, and the system got stuck without reporting an error. Does anyone know the reason? If I need to upgrade my version, which version should I upgrade to? Do I need to change the original query sql after upgrading the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to upgrade your Apache IoTDB version, since Version 0.12 is no longer maintained. You can upgrade to Version 0.13.3 without changing your query SQL. However, if you want stronger performance (like cluster arrangement), you may need to upgrade to Version 1.0 and above, but your SQL grammar may need to be checked.